# Conditional in IF statement not being met?

Tags: php

The purpose of this function is to print the factorial of any given number. Except when I run it, I get the very last factor to be calculated only, in this case, 20 * 1. I'm pretty sure this is because the first condition in my if/else statement is never being met, but I cannot figure out why.

```
<?php
  function factorializer($factorial){
    $factorialResult = 0;
    for($i = $factorial; $i > 1; $i--){
      $tempResult = $factorial * ($i-1);
      if($tempResult == $factorialResult){
        $factorialResult = $factorialResult + $tempResult;
      }
      else{
        $factorialResult = $tempResult;
      }
    }
      print($factorialResult);
  }
  factorializer(20);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no addition in factorial, factorial uses multiplication. i also don't think you need to use an `if` here either

```
$result = 1;
for($i = $factorial; $i > 1; $i--) {
     $result *= $i;
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing $tempResult and $factorialResult, $factorialResult will always be the value of $tempResult + $factorial (after the first iteration). You're right, the if statement is never true the way you have it set up.

All I know is that there seems to be a built-in PHP function for factorials: gmp_fact(20) - (http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-fact.php)

Logan Murphy's answer seems to work well and is probably the simplest way to do it aside from the built-in.